# fread only reading in from the first time I ran the program

Tags: c, arrays, struct, fwrite, fread

When I first run I would add 3 records, which gives me a count of 3. Then I `fwrite` the count into a bin file, and the records into a bin file, then I close the program.

When I reopen it and then I `fread` in and it will give me my 3 records and a count of 3. But from there on, no matter if I back up or when I read in, it will give me the same count 3 and 3 records, though since the count isn't being updated either this may be why `fread` is only reading in the first time records.

I am not sure why the counter isn't updating. Both `fread` and `fwrite` are returning = success so I am not sure what`s up.

```
void backUp(PAYROLL employee[], long int *pCounter)
{
    FILE *counter;
        errno_t result1 = fopen_s(&counter, "c:\\myFiles\\counter.bin", "a+b");
        if (result1 == 0){
            fwrite(pCounter, sizeof(long int), 1, counter);
            fclose(counter);
        }
        else
            printf("Back up of counter failed! error:%d",result1);

    FILE *record;

        errno_t result2 = fopen_s(&record, "c:\\myFiles\\record.bin", "a+b");
        if (result2 == 0){
            fwrite(employee, *pCounter *sizeof(PAYROLL), 1, record);
            fclose(record);
        }

        else
            printf("Back up of record failed! error:%d", result2);
}

void upload(PAYROLL employee[], long int *pCounter)
{
    FILE *counter;
    errno_t result1 = fopen_s(&counter, "c:\\myFiles\\counter.bin", "a+b");
    if (result1 == 0){
        result = fread(pCounter, sizeof(long int), 1, counter);
        fclose(counter);
        printf("Counter:%d", *pCounter);
    }
    else
        printf("Upload up of counter failed!");
    FILE *record;
    errno_t result2 = fopen_s(&record, "c:\\myFiles\\record.bin", "r+b");
    if (result2 == 0)
    {

            result2 = fread(employee, *pCounter *sizeof(PAYROLL), 1, record);
            printf("Upload successful!\n");

        fclose(record);
    }
    else
        printf("Error opening file!");
}
```

Comment: How do you know that `fread` and `fwrite` are returning "success" when you have not checked their return value?

Comment: I look through the debugger and step in to the function, result is giving me their success return values (if thats how it works)

Comment: You still need that in the program. Without that sort of checking, your code will be blown over by a puff of wind.

Comment: Looks like everywhere you open in append mode `"a+b"` you should probably be using something else (`"rb"` in `upload()` and `"wb"` in `backUp()` possibly?)

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't understand, is there a specific function for error checking? As I had always thought that error checking was just looking at what goes in the value of result and then I can go check what the value means?

Comment: Look at the specification of [`fread()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html) and [`fwrite()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fwrite.html).  They return the number of records written or read, which may be less than the number requested.  If you get a short write, then you have a problem — maybe out of disk space.  If you get a short read, it may be that you requested 100 records but there were only 1 or 10 or 99 available to read (or there was an error).  If you don't capture and check the return value, you've no idea what happened.

Comment: It's not fair to commenters to add `result = fread...` to your submission *after* their point has been made. And you need to compare that `result` with the number of records you intended to read, or write, as @JonathanLeffler commented. With writing, to check if the write was successful. With reading, this might also remove the need to keep a separate file holding the number of records.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yea, I see they read and write 1, but it still stores the first  3 elements of my struct array. I assume its one because its only writing my array? Files are fairly new to me and I've been trying to grasp them for the past couple of days now

Comment: `fread()` (and `fwrite()` too) give you considerable flexibility because you can supply the size of an item and the number of items separately.  You use `result2 = fread(employee, *pCounter *sizeof(PAYROLL), 1, record);`.  This tells `fread()` to read 1 item of size `*pCounter * sizeof(PAYROLL)`. You will get a result of 1 (success) or 0 (failure). You could have specified: `result2 = fread(employee, sizeof(PAYROLL), *pCounter, record);` which would tell you how many records of size `sizeof(PAYROLL)` were read, up to a maximum of the value in `*pCounter`. You might get 0 or 1 or …

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the second option you listed gives me an unhandled exception error

Comment: That suggests there's something else amiss in code we cannot see.  Futzing the numbers from `*pCounter * sizeof(PAYROLL)` and `1` to `sizeof(PAYROLL)` and `*pCounter` should not change anything except the return value from `fread()`.  If it does, it was accidental that the original code worked.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler LefflerI have no idea where else could be the problem, as every thing has been working fine, I was pretty much done I just needed to find out how to work a file lol

Comment: I suspect you made a typo in the modified call to `fread()` then.  Take another good look.  Did you omit the `*` from `*pCounter`, for example?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler 
`result2 = fread(employee, sizeof(PAYROLL), *pCounter, 1, record);`
Is what I have down aaand i just realized whats wrong lol and the return value for result2 is 2 which is good I just need it to upload more when I back up more

Comment: Check the mode strings you open the files with.  Append mode positions you at the end of the file, when you need to be at the start -- you've got two `"a+b"`'s that should be `"wb"`, and one `"a+b"` that should be `"rb"`.

Comment: How come your compiler let you call `fread()` with the wrong number of arguments?  You haven't got something right in your compiler options!  That should be an error.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have no idea, I am using Visual Studios 2013, also Dimitri thanks I saw your comment up above but I was kind of confused about it but when you commented again it clicked and it solved the problem also thank you Jonathan because your comments also helped me understand a bit on how files worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring the most salient comments into an answer.*</sup>

[Weathervane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142924/weather-vane) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186823/#comment46588873_29186823):

> How do you know that `fread` and `fwrite` are returning "success" when you have not checked their return value?

[Jude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4076958/jude) commented:

> I look through the debugger and step in to the function, result is giving me their success return values (if that's how it works).

[Weathervane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142924/weather-vane) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186823/#comment46588969_29186823):

> You still need that in the program. Without that sort of checking, your code will be blown over by a puff of wind.

[Dmitri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/929459/dmitri) correctly [observed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186823/#comment46589009_29186823):

> Looks like everywhere you open in append mode "a+b" you should probably be using something else ("rb" in upload() and "wb" in backUp() possibly?)

[Jude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4076958/jude) commented:

> I don't understand, is there a specific function for error checking? As I had always thought that error checking was just looking at what goes in the value of result and then I can go check what the value means?

Look at the specification of [`fread()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html) and
[`fwrite()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fwrite.html). They return the number of records written or read, which may be less than the number requested. If you get a short write, then you have a problem — maybe out of disk space. If you get a short read, it may be that you requested 100 records but there were only 1 or 10 or 99 available to read (or there was an error). If you don't capture and check the return value, you've no idea what happened.

[Jude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4076958/jude) commented:

> I see they read and write 1, but it still stores the first 3 elements of my struct array. I assume it's one because it's only writing my array?

`fread()` (and `fwrite()` too) give you considerable flexibility because you can supply the size of an item and the number of items separately. You use:

```
result2 = fread(employee, *pCounter *sizeof(PAYROLL), 1, record);
```

This tells `fread()` to read `1` item of size `*pCounter * sizeof(PAYROLL)`. You will get a result of `1` (success) or `0` (failure). You could have specified:

```
result2 = fread(employee, sizeof(PAYROLL), *pCounter, record);
```

which would tell you how many records of size `sizeof(PAYROLL)` were read, up to a maximum of the value in `*pCounter`. You might get 0 or 1 or …

Here is some workable code that does more or less what's required.  The `main()` program demonstrates working with 1, 2 and 3 records (and the names are a few kings and queens of England, along with the year of their ascension to the throne as their employee ID number).  I had to create a minimal payroll structure since the question didn't provide one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct PAYROLL
{
    long emp_id;
    char emp_name[32];
} PAYROLL;

static const char counter_bin[] = "counter.bin";
static const char records_bin[] = "records.bin";

static
void backUp(PAYROLL employee[], long int *pCounter)
{
    FILE *counter = fopen(counter_bin, "wb");
    if (counter != 0){
        fwrite(pCounter, sizeof(long int), 1, counter);
        fclose(counter);
    }
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Back up of counter failed! error: %d %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));

    FILE *record = fopen(records_bin, "wb");
    if (record != 0){
        fwrite(employee, *pCounter *sizeof(PAYROLL), 1, record);
        fclose(record);
    }
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Back up of records failed! error: %d %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
}

static
void upload(PAYROLL employee[], long int *pCounter)
{
    FILE *counter = fopen(counter_bin, "rb");
    if (counter != 0){
        size_t result = fread(pCounter, sizeof(long int), 1, counter);
        fclose(counter);
        if (result != 0)
            printf("Counter: %ld\n", *pCounter);
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read counter\n");
    }
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Upload up of counter failed!\n");

    FILE *record = fopen(records_bin, "r+b");
    if (record != 0)
    {
        size_t result2 = fread(employee, *pCounter * sizeof(PAYROLL), 1, record);
        if (result2 == 1)
            printf("Upload successful!\n");
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read records!\n");
        fclose(record);
    }
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file!");
}

int main(void)
{
    PAYROLL emps[] =
    {
        { 1066, "William the Conqueror" },
        { 1819, "Victoria" },
        { 1689, "William and Mary" },
    };

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        long emp_count = i;
        printf("Employee count = %ld\n", emp_count);
        backUp(emps, &emp_count);
        upload(emps, &emp_count);
        for (int j = 0; j < emp_count; j++)
            printf("%4ld: %s\n", emps[j].emp_id, emps[j].emp_name);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I've factored out the file names so that you only have to change a single line to change the files used.  Sample output:

```
$ Employee count = 1
Counter: 1
Upload successful!
1066: William the Conqueror
Employee count = 2
Counter: 2
Upload successful!
1066: William the Conqueror
1819: Victoria
Employee count = 3
Counter: 3
Upload successful!
1066: William the Conqueror
1819: Victoria
1689: William and Mary
$ odx counter.bin
0x0000: 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                           ........
0x0008:
$ odx records.bin
0x0000: 2A 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 57 69 6C 6C 69 61 6D 20   *.......William 
0x0010: 74 68 65 20 43 6F 6E 71 75 65 72 6F 72 00 00 00   the Conqueror...
0x0020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1B 07 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0x0030: 56 69 63 74 6F 72 69 61 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   Victoria........
0x0040: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0x0050: 99 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 57 69 6C 6C 69 61 6D 20   ........William 
0x0060: 61 6E 64 20 4D 61 72 79 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   and Mary........
0x0070: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                           ........
0x0078:
$
```

(`odx` is just a hex dump program.  Pick your own program that does an equivalent job — `od -c` is a fallback, though I don't particularly like its formatting.)

Answer (score 1):

I see many faults in your program.

Firstly, you are writing long ints and PAYROLL structures directly to a file. You should never do that, as structures and integers have a machine-dependent representation and if you write the files on one machine (let's say 32-bit machine) and read them on another machine (let's say 64-bit machine) then you might run into problems.

Secondly, you're not checking the return value of fread(). It should be always checked.

Thirdly, you're assigning the return value of fread() to an errno_t. Are you sure you really want to do that?

If you want to have the answer to the actual problem, consider updating the source code to fix the mistakes I pointed out and consider improving the English language in your question. Furthermore, you should provide a complete example, i.e. one that contains the definition of PAYROLL. When you know the actual return value of fread(), perhaps the problem will be easier to track down then.

Comment: fread is returning 1 I already checked the return value with result i forgot to add a result to one of the freads but it is returning 1 and I've been told by other people to include errno_t I didn't know it'd be a problem.

Comment: Re 'firstly': it is perfectly OK to write binary data to disk as long as you are aware of the limitations on portability.  Granted, if the data must be moved between 32-bit and 64-bit machines, or between CPUs of different types (e.g. SPARC and Intel), then you have to work hard.  But for a training exercise where the portability is not required (and where binary I/O probably is required), it is OK to use `fread()` and `fwrite()`.